# ContentControl in front of all Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, window, always-on-top

In our WPF app we have one Main Window and a bunch of buttons that open pop-up Edit/ReadOnly Windows. In the Main Window we also have a ContentControl that gives notifications in the bottom right corner.

What I want to achieve is to have these notifications pop-up in the very front of all Windows. I know I can use `Panel.ZIndex` to make it the front View-Element inside the (Main) Window itself, but I'd also want it on top of the pop-up Windows that might be in front of it.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know I could put this ContentControl with Notifications inside a seperate Window instead of the MainWindow itself, but then I'd had to remove the borders and bar of the Window, remove it from the Windows Taskbar at the bottom and a bunch of other stuff to make it look/act the same as it is right now, which I preferably avoid.

So, what is the best way to approach this and is it even possible without putting it in a seperate Window, and have that pop up in front of every other window every time a new Notifications comes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have a choice to make as the only way to make your `ContentControl` appear on top of other `Window`s is to put it into its own `Window` and set its `TopMost` property to `true`. As it is, the `Panel.ZIndex` will only affect the Z index of the control *within* the `MainWindow`... you can't set it to be displayed above the level of the parent `Window`.

So in short, your solution is to add your `ContentControl` to a custom `Window` and make *that* appear on top.

Comment: I was indeed afraid that might be the case.. I'll await some more answers, try some things out and most likely make a new question since I don't really know how to make a Window appear borderless (also excluding the `- [] X` at the top right) and also let it not appear in the Windows Task Bar.. Will probably make this issue a lower priority though, since we have some more things to do in our project before the holidays.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions here... there are many examples of borderless `Window`s already online, eg. [WPF borderless window with shadow VS2012 style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730311/wpf-borderless-window-with-shadow-vs2012-style).