# Draw to an image then render that image to a window with a transparent background?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

### WinForms Project

Im trying to draw to an image then draw that to a window that is external to my application using:

```
using(var g = Graphics.FromHandle(handle))
g.DrawImage(myImage);
```

to reduce flickering behavior when drawing.

I know that I can use the `BufferedGraphics` class, but it had a black background so I tried to draw a transparent image to it first and then draw on top of that but it still had a black background when rendering it.

Is there any way to use `BufferedGraphics` or a way of drawing once to memory so it can be drawn as a whole image at once (to reduce flickering) to screen with a transparent background?

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25450799/1812199

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you are using a timer and drawing the image each time the tick event fires and that's the reason of the flickering

So, first create a winform, i am putting the backColor to red so you can see the transparency of the background better

[image]

Add one timer and turn on the tick event
Then choose an image with transparency in png, one like this:

[image]

Put it in the directory where you start your application from

[image]

Finally this is the code, it's fully functional, i tested already :v

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
System.Data;
System.Drawing;
System.IO;
System.Linq;
System.Text;
System.Threading.Tasks;
System.Windows.Forms;
namespace so
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Image image;
    public Form1()
    {
        image = Image.FromFile("imagen.png");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
        BufferedGraphicsContext bgc = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        BufferedGraphics bg = bgc.Allocate(gr,this.ClientRectangle);
        //before drawing the image clean the background with the current form's Backcolor
        bg.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
        //use any overload of drawImage, the best for your project
        bg.Graphics.DrawImage(image,0,0);
        bg.Render(gr);
    }
}
}
```

Maybe i didn't understand correctly your answer, but this will avoid the flickering and show one image with transparent background without any problem :)

Comment: Hi there, Thank-you for this although answer although the window is external to my application. Sorry I should have mentioned that in the original question, ive updated it now.